# Does YAML::Node have a Mark structure?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I know that during parsing, yaml-cpp can throw an exception that has nice file location (line and column number) information for where the exception occurred.
How about post-parse?  Is there any mechanism to determine the (first) line number of a YAML file that is associated with a given node?

Answer (score 5):

Starting with 0.5.3 YAML::Node has a property Mark() to get information about line number etc.

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't, but this is an open feature request - see [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=200) on the project page.

Comment: This is obsolete and no longer correct. There is the Mark() method on the node.